# How to get a specific record from RDD by using Python

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I am working in RDD by using Python. I want to find a specific record from this RDD

```
(8, 23, 4.0)
(50, 21, 3.0)
(5, 48, 3.0)
(5, 85, 3.0)
(40, 17, 3.0)
(3, 62, 3.0)
(24, 92, 3.0)
(48, 24, 3.0)
(48, 73, 3.0)
(34, 48, 3.0)    
(50, 14, 3.0)
(1, 78, 3.0)
(7, 8, 3.0)
(10, 87, 3.0)
(14, 82, 3.0)
```

**For Example**: I want to find the 3rd value when `1st is 3` and `2nd is 62`, so it should return `3.0`. The tuple is `(3,62,3.0)`, The 6th from top in RDD

I am not aware about correct terminology to use since I am a beginner with Spark and Python. I am not getting how to use filter or map function or which one to use.

Comment: Filter reduces your dataset and mapping applys a function over all rows. Mapping will not give you one record. Please show your attempts at filtering

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to find 3rd value when 1st is 3 and 2nd is 62

You gave your exact requirements, and you seem to know about map and filter functions, so the rest is only an understanding of regular python tuple unpacking and lambda functions.

```
reduced_rdd = rdd.filter(lambda x: x[0] == 3 and x[1] == 62)\
  .map(lambda x: x[2])
```

Answer (score 1):

This will return all values where first value is 3 and second one 62:

```
records = [(8, 23, 4.0)
(50, 21, 3.0)
(5, 48, 3.0)
(5, 85, 3.0)
(40, 17, 3.0)
(3, 62, 3.0)
(24, 92, 3.0)
(48, 24, 3.0)
(48, 73, 3.0)
(34, 48, 3.0)    
(50, 14, 3.0)
(1, 78, 3.0)
(7, 8, 3.0)
(10, 87, 3.0)
(14, 82, 3.0)]

rdd = sc.parallelize(records)
rdd.filter(lambda x: x[0] == 3 and x[1] == 63)
rdd.map( lambda x: (x[2],) )
```

In `filter()` you can set which records you would like to keep.
In `map()` you can change what will record contain.

Comment: Hey Agata, Thank a lot for walking extra mile. At the moment RDD has unique combinations but this is very helpful and may help in some future implementation.

Comment: Why are you calling `.collect()`?